# How to return a first, second last instance of the event in the same row? POWER BI

Tags: powerbi

I am looking for assistance to come up with a formula to display pictures (via URL) of first, second and last occurrence of the event in the table in which the events are grouped by item names and category (every single event has a image of its own).
I seemed to try everything  I can think of, and got nowhere. The following is the principle of the data sheet:

[image]

Please have in mind that these events of same items can occur in several places and they all have their own image. So my objective is to display several images as examples in one line. (probably it is best to display them in different columns??

My expected results should look similar to as the following:

[image]

Could any of you help me out with coming up with formulas to do something like that?

Looking forward to any help/guidance,

Comment: How exactly are the images related to the URLs? E.g. what is the URL for Event3-image2?

Comment: Hi Andrew,
As you can see in the count column, there are 6 images of the event where item1 and Item2 meet(it may also be that item1 and item 2 switch places in the columns, but nevertheless they meet), and all these 6 occurrences have unique image. All the images are placed in dropbox and connected to the events by the index. Hope it makes it more clear. 
If you have more questions, please do ask, so I could try to explain it